# Initiating selection in replacement for Emacs' forward-word

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to replace Emacs' default forward-word and backward-word to operate more like Visual Studio's - which I find better suited to Perl programming. I first tried hacking the syntax table, without achieving the effect I wanted. Then I came up with the following:

```
(defconst perl-movement-stop-chars "a-zA-Z$@%_0-9'")
(defconst perl-movement-stop-pattern (concat "[" perl-movement-stop-chars "]"))
(defconst non-perl-movement-stop-pattern (concat "[^" perl-movement-stop-chars "]"))

(defun perl-forward-word ()
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-at perl-movement-stop-pattern)
      (progn
        (if (re-search-forward non-perl-movement-stop-pattern nil t)
            (backward-char)))
    (if (re-search-forward perl-movement-stop-pattern nil t)
        (backward-char))))

(defun perl-backward-word ()
  (interactive)
  (backward-char)
  (if (looking-at perl-movement-stop-pattern)
      (progn
        (if (re-search-backward non-perl-movement-stop-pattern nil t)
            (forward-char)))
    (if (re-search-backward perl-movement-stop-pattern nil t)
        (forward-char))))

(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (local-set-key [C-right] 'perl-forward-word)
            (local-set-key [C-left] 'perl-backward-word)
            linum-mode))
```

This does what I want - nearly: I still have to handle the case when moving backward from inside the first word in the buffer. But that is not my question.

The problem with this is that the selection is not started when I type C-S-right, as it is when my hook is not installed (or in other modes). If I initiate the selection though (e.g. by hitting first S-right) my functions do extend it.

I know very, very little about elisp programming and I am just guessing my way here. I would appreciate a bit of help. Thanks...

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to achieve (rather than saying "operate more like Visual Studio's") and what is happening right now.

Comment: When the point is on a "stop" characters [a-zA-Z$@%_0-9'], I want to move forward (or backward) until it is not anymore. And when it is not on a stop character, I want to move until it is. In other words, I want to move easily from inside a "word" to its end then to the beginning of next "word", then just past end of next "word", etc - my definition of "word" being a bit non standard though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `shift-select-mode` working, you'll need to use `(interactive "^")`.  Try `C-h f interactive RET`.

BTW, you can simplify your code considerably: to move forward, just `(re-search-forward ".\\(\\_<\\|\\_>\\)" nil t)` and to move backward, use `(re-search-backward "\\(\\_<\\|\\_>\\)." nil t)`.

Comment: Thanks. The BTW suggestion doesn't give the result I want, I suppose because it relies on the normal definition of a word as per the syntax table (then maybe I should alter the syntax table). However, the (interactive "^") suggestion is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Specifially, it jumps over the second "use" in:

use strict;
use warnings;

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your particular problem, but I suspect the problem is just that `.` should be replaced by `\\(.\\|\n\\)` in the two regexps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but I thought I'd offer this.  I have a package which I call [syntax-subword](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/syntax-subword) (available in Melpa).  It makes word movement more fine-grained, to the point where I hardly ever move by characters, and use other solutions like isearch to move bigger distances.

From the comments:

```
;; This package provides `syntax-subword' minor mode, which extends
;; `subword-mode' to make word editing and motion more fine-grained.
;; Basically, it makes syntax changes, CamelCaseWords, and the normal
;; word boundaries the boundaries for word operations.  Here's an
;; example of where the cursor stops using `forward-word' in
;; `emacs-lisp-mode':
;;
;; (defun FooBar (arg) "doc string"
;; |     |      |    |     |      |  standard
;; |     |   |  |    |     |      |  subword-mode
;; ||    ||  |  |||  ||||  ||     || syntax-subword-mode
;; ||     |      ||  | ||   |     |  vim
```