# How to change the way that emacs move over a word?

Tags: emacs

I am a junior emacser . I want to know how to change the way that ·emacs· recognize the words.

For example ,   I am at the end of line : `(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 13)))` , now `M-b` to move backward over a word:

(use symbol `|` to mark the caret postion)

**emacs:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size |13)))`
**sublime:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 13|)))`

`M-b` agian

**emacs:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :|size 13)))`
**sublime:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size |13)))`

`M-b` several times

**emacs:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" |:size 13)))`
**sublime:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" |:size 13)))`

`M-b` agian

**emacs:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft |YaHei" :size 13)))`
**sublime:**`(font-spec :family "Microsoft YaHei|" :size 13)))`

`M-b` several times

**emacs:**`(font-spec :|family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 13)))`
**sublime:**`(font-spec :|family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 13)))`

`M-b` agian

**emacs:**`(font-|spec :family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 13)))`
**sublime:**`(font-spec |:family "Microsoft YaHei" :size 13)))`

The way move over a word of `emacs` is too stange to adapt it . I prefer the way of `sublime`. I want to know how to change the way that emacs move over a word.thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16043393/245173

Comment: I use my own -- one of the first things I did to customize the Emacs experience, because I came from a word-processing background:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675201/alternative-to-forward-word-backward-word-to-include-symbols-e-g

Comment: The behavior in Sublime sounds like it jumps to the next word *boundary.* This is not hard to do (and then bind to M-b if you like), but it's not what "moving backwards one word" means.

Comment: fantastic!!! I find answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034357/initiating-selection-in-replacement-for-emacs-forward-word/16043393#16043393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs uses *syntax tables*, whereby each character belongs to a specified *syntax class*. The syntax table may vary between buffers, usually according to the requirements of the major modes in use.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Syntax Tables` <kbd>RET</kbd>

`forward-word` and `backward-word` find the next/previous character of 'word' syntax, and then skip past all subsequent consecutive 'word' syntax characters.

I don't know what rules Sublime is using, and can't establish that from your examples, but *maybe* something like this would be more to your liking?

```el
(defun my-backward-word-or-other ()
  "Move over the preceding word or non-word characters."
  (interactive)
  (unless (bobp)
    (if (eq ?w (char-syntax (char-before)))
        (backward-word)
      (skip-syntax-backward "^w"))))

(defun my-forward-word-or-other ()
  "Move over the following word or non-word characters."
  (interactive)
  (unless (eobp)
    (if (eq ?w (char-syntax (char-after)))
        (forward-word)
      (skip-syntax-forward "^w"))))

(global-set-key [remap forward-word] 'my-forward-word-or-other)
(global-set-key [remap backward-word] 'my-backward-word-or-other)
```

Comment: I try the elisp code fragment in .emacs file . But I meet a exception `Symbol's function definition is void : case`. what is wrong? by the way , Syntax Tables is hard to understand T_T

Comment: Apologies, my fault. I used `case` which requires `cl` to be loaded. I've converted that to a simple `if` form with no such dependency. And yes, syntax tables probably aren't a beginner subject; but if you want to understand what Emacs is doing here, that's what is behind the logic.

Comment: Thx for your answer . and now I am trying to custom the way that move over a word like sublime